# Mod Rewrite exclude folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have effectively used the rewrite rule to change my url from /teams.php?team=New York Yankees&year=2012 to teams/New York Yankees/2012.

My .htaccess file contains the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^teams/([^/]*)/(^/]*)$ /teams.php?team=$1&year=$2 [L]
```

However, with this rewrite rule currently in effect, none of the external CSS and JS files will load. I've tried putting the following rewrite condition before the rewrite rule with no luck

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css/js)/
```

Almost all of my files have the following link to the external stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use full paths when linking to your stylesheets, not relative paths like you have now.  With the rewrite rules in place they become relative to the pre-rewritten URL.

For example, change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css" />
```

The reason they are not loading is because the browser is trying to access:

```
http://yoursite.com/teams/New York Yankees/2012/css/stylesheet.css
```

when you link to `css/stylesheet` which of course does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But, is there another rewrite rule that I could use that would make it so that I wouldn't have to edit each file individually just to change "css/stylsheet.css" to "/css/stylsheet.css"

Comment: If you have repetitive code like that, I'd recommend putting it in a header file so you don't have to change lots of files each time you need to change something common.  You could use this perl one-liner to search and replace across many files: `perl -p -i -e 's/"css/"\/css/g' `find ./ -name *`   Rewriting in order to solve this problem isn't a good idea in my opinion.  You just end up creating more virtual URL's when it is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that might be a problem. I have included lots of other repetitive code in files that i just use require_once to include in the likes other files. Since, if I change it in the one file that is included in all the others, then the changes are universal. Has saved me lots of time but I never really contemplated using mod rewrite to make pretty url's until recently. Looking back in retrospect, I should have...

Comment: All part of learning, now you know and next time you will probably work to break up the layout code so you can re-use pieces of it :)   Hopefully there aren't too many CSS references you have to change, or you get a quick search and replace working and be done with it as painlessly as possible.